# Tell SVN to only import specific file types into repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Instead of setting the Global ignore pattern to ignore specific file types, I think it would be easier to just tell it to only include specific file types.  Is this possible?

For example, I ONLY want .java files under version control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem directly possible, however:

1. Before a commit 'svn add *.java' and simly ignore any other files in 'svn st', et. al. (simplest, but a little ugly);
2. Write a pre-commit hook that fails the commit if any files do not end in .java (sort of ugly, and if you change your mind you have to change the hook);
3. Set ignore=* and then remember that you *must* 'svn add *.java' when adding any new files (quite ugly and prone to data loss if you forget).

If you decide to go the global route then consider setting the svn:ignore property on your project directory or directories instead.  That way, non- *.java files in other types of projects will continue to act normally.